# Warn before breaking references in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

Editing a larger document in Word, I want to remove some equations, but there are text-marks on their numbering.

[image: ...]

The equation is now obsolete and should be removed. If I do so and update fields (<kbd>Ctrl+A, F9</kbd>), some cross-references are broken, and I need to manually skim through the document to find them. Since it affects multiple equations I am confronted with two bad choices:

1. After each removed text mark, manually skim the document for broken references and update the cross-reference to point to the new contents.
2. After removing the obsolete equations, go through the document once, but for each broken reference finding out what it was originally pointing too and what it should now point to becomes much harder.

Is there some possibility to instead get a list of broken references, after each removal, so I can update the cross-references without having to repeatedly skim the document manually?

For comparison, in LaTeX the same workflow would simply require reviewing the log file for "undefined reference" warnings, which LaTeX editors like TexStudio typically make trivial.

Comment: There’s no built in feature, VBA could generate a list of broken refs, but  IMO if you insert the new equations before deleting, you could have a process like this: (1) immediately after the equation you’re going to delete, create one cross-reference for each reference you’re going to delete, in the same sequence. Select the equation, and have VBA build a table of old bookmarks vs. New bookmarks, iterate through the REF fields in the document looking for the old bookmarks and replacing them by the new ones, then delete the equation and those refs you inserted.

Comment: Sadly, I also have situations where text marks aren't used for anything but generating "(16a), (16b)" style numbering; The only way to do this seems to be to make the first "16" an automatically numbered field, and the other "16"s in "16b", "16c", ... cross references to the first. At the same time, it is entirely possible for parts of the text to make a reference to the whole equation group "16". As a consequence, when editing collaborative documents, any manual solution takes a LOT of effort. A VBA based solution would be possible, but I don't currently know VBA.

Comment: Anyway, it is good for a solution to be possible. But unless someone has already written one, I can't really apply it :/

Comment: Just as a comment on the 16, 16a, 16b numbering, if you use a { SEQ eqnum } field for the number you can use { SEQ EQNUM \c } to repeat it, no xref required.

Comment: In vba you can iterate the cross references, update each and check for error ('error cross reference source not found'). Then if error, undo and take whatever action to correct. Eg. show a form with current reference value and let user choose a new reference.